# Strange behavior of Void and intersection types

Tags: scala, covariance

Is this the expected behavior?

```
scala> val l: List[Void] = "I'm void".asInstanceOf[String with Void] :: Nil
l: List[Void] = List(I'm void)
```

Is valid to recognize `l` as `List[Void]` and show a `String` as the first element?

Comment: It's not showing a `String` as the first element.  It's showing a `String with Void` as the first element.

Comment: In testing, I'm getting the following error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Void`.  What version of scala are you using? I can't replicate your output in 2.11.7.

Comment: @soong I tried in several. You are getting the error probably if you try to access the value inside the `List`. Something like `l.head`.

Comment: I copied the example code you gave into a Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ.  I've tried with the REPL and that does seem to work, but I think m-z's answer covers what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely valid, in a sense, and is not specific to `Void`. By itself, `"I'm void".asInstanceOf[String with Void]` will *not* throw a `ClassCastException` until you actually try to use it in an way that would require treating it as an invalid type.

```
val l: List[Void] = "I'm void".asInstanceOf[String with Void] :: Nil
```

This is valid, because we're lying to the compiler to say `"I'm void"` is an instance of `String with Void`, and `String with Void` is a sub-type of `Void`, which means we can, *for a moment* have a `List[Void]`, since `List[String with Void] <: List[Void]`. *However*, if we try to access to the head of the `List[Void]`, we expect a `Void`, which the original `String` is not.

```
scala> l.head
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Void
```

It appears to work at first, because everything has a `toString` method, so it doesn't need to be treated as anything other than `Any`.

The same thing happens if we try it with `String with Int`.

```
scala> val int = "I'm an Int".asInstanceOf[String with Int]
int: String with Int = I'm an Int

scala> int % 2
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

The `String with Int` will happily exist until reality sets in, and we realize it isn't actually an `Int`, and doesn't have a `%` method.

Answer (score 2):

A slight extension to @m-z's answer to explain *why* `.asInstanceOf[String with Void]` doesn't throw. We need to distinguish what exists in Scala and what exists in JVM bytecode. In particular, bytecode doesn't support intersection types like `String with Void` and therefore can't cast to it. So the bytecode emitted for `.asInstanceOf[String with Void]` is actually the same as for `.asInstanceOf[String]`; but when the compiler sees values of this type used as `Void`, it'll insert additional casts.

This is the same reason why you can't distinguish generic types with different parameters (like `List[Int]` and `List[String]`) using `isInstanceOf`: so far as bytecode is concerned, the types are the same.

Comment: Note that if you invert `String` and `Void` in the intersection type, you'll get a `ClassCastException` before `l` gets constructed.

Comment: Yes, this follows because you get the cast to `Void` in bytecode in this case.